# Is it possible to get SSLHandshakeException if IP is not whitelisted?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I am trying to hit an external endpoint. I am getting

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

This error could only occur AFTER a connection has been made right?

If my IP was blocked, I would have gotten a different error like connection timeout or connection reset.

Comment: I would expect a Connection Refused or Connection Timeout issue if you were unable to reach the endpoint at all.

Comment: yeah I also gravitate towards the same answer.

Comment: do you have your `TLS` setup?

Comment: Yes Vishrant I have. I have tried everything that is found on the internet to resolve that. It is not working. Can you please just answer me the question? `This error could only occur AFTER a connection has been made right?

If my IP was blocked, I would have gotten a different error like connection timeout or connection reset.`